# Jquery delete dynamically created draggable divs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

Im dynamically creating divs with a button using this function

```
var counter = 1;
$("#button1").click(function(){
 $("<div/>", {
   "class": "test" + (counter++),
    text: "",
  }).resizable().draggable()
  .appendTo("body");
});
```

How would I add another button in order to delete these dynamically created divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
 $("<div/>", {
   "class": "dynamic test" + (counter++),
    text: "",
  }).append('<div id="button"' + (counter -1) + '">Close</div>').resizable().draggable()
  .appendTo("body");

  $("#button" + (counter -1)).click(function(){
      $(".test" + (counter-1)).remove();
   });
});
```

You can also append close button on each created div inorder to close that div

Comment: The question makes it sound like the author was looking for a single button to remove all dynamically created divs? Oh well, there are problems with this code. 1) You're using double quotes to start the string `append("<div id="button"` but also for the attribute? That isn't right, tell tell sign that the highlighting of the code isn't right.

Comment: Thanks, i changed the quotation part.I think, author want to create close button for each div.Other way, it is easy to create  a single button for delete all the created div.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just give a generic class to each dynamically added element, in this case `.dynamic`. Then when another button is pressed just removed any instance of that class.

```
var counter = 1;

$("#button1").click(function(){
 $("<div/>", {
   "class": "dynamic test" + (counter++), // note we're adding a new generic class
    text: "",
  }).resizable().draggable()
  .appendTo("body");
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
 $(".dynamic").remove();
});
```